# Angular Two-Way-Databind - Change Value

Tags: angular, input, angular4-forms, ngmodel

I Have one Form with an input.

```
<form #modelContrato="ngForm" role="form" >
<input [(ngModel)]="modelContrato.numero" id="numero" class="form-control" name="numero" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Número Contrato"
                                        #numero="ngModel" required />
```

On my component.ts I have these lines.

```
@Input() modelContrato: Contrato;
```

On Constructor

```
this.modelContrato = {} as Contrato;
```

ngOnInit

```
this.modelContrato.numero = '10';
```

ps: Contrato is a model. Like This

```
export interface Contrato {
    id: string;
    contratoPrincipalId: string;
    numero: string;
}
```

Why my input not change de value passed in OnInit ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic solution: work with `@ViewChild` to refer to an Element.
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Your personal problem solution: just create a field in your component

`const modelContrato: Contrato;`

since the `[(ngModel)]="modelContrato.numero"` two-way binds to the modelContrato numero attribute to the input-element value

Why your Code wont work: you misstook the `input` Element to be bound to `@input` decorator.
The `@input` Decorator is for passing properties from ancestor to successor Components.
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Where do i put "const modelContrato: Contrato;" ? 
I have this interface declared OnInit.

Do I need to change something in my html component ?